# Zend Framework (1.12) Navigation combined with regex routing nightmare

Tags: zend-framework, navigation, routes

I have a simple navigation setup in xml, that looks like this:

```
<nav>
    <page1>
        <controller>foo</controller>
        <route>default</route>
        <pages>
            <p1sub1>
                <controller>foo</controller>
                <action>bar</action>
                <route>foobar</route>
                <params>
                    <bar>specialId</bar>
                </params>
            </p1sub1>
            <p1sub2>
                <controller>foo</controller>
                <action>bum</action>
            </p1sub2>
        </pages>
    </page1>
    <page2>
        <controller>fee</controller>
        <route>default</route>
        <pages>
            <p2sub1>
                <controller>fee</controller>
                <action>zip</action>
            </p2sub1>
            <p2sub2>
                <controller>fee</controller>
                <action>zap</action>
            </p2sub2>
        </pages>
    </page2>
</nav>
```

Coupled with a route definition that looks like this:

```
routes.foobar.route = "foo/:specialId/bar"
routes.foobar.defaults.controller = foo
routes.foobar.defaults.action = bar
routes.foobar.defaults.specialId = 999
```

In my bootstrap, I'm assigning this navigation config to the view thusly:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml('path/to/nav.xml', 'nav');
$navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
$this->getResource('layoutview')->navigation($navigation);
```

Then, in my layout, I'm doing this to render the top level:

```
<?= $this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(0) ?>
```

The next level of menu needs to be rendered in the view script for the invoked controller action, thusly:

```
<?= $this->navigation()->menu()->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)->setRenderParents(false) ?>
```

If I visit /foo/bum, /fee/zip, or /fee/zap it all works as expected. I get two correctly rendered menus, with the corrent menu items highlighted. Marvellous. However... When I visit /foo/123/bar, I get no menus at all. I've spent HOURS looking at this now, debugging/single-stepping through the inheritance nightmare that is Zend navigation and its associated menu rendering, but I simply cannot see why it's doing this. I can't see the wood for the trees anymore. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical. Within minutes of posting, I solved it myself. I simply removed the **params** node from the XML definition of the navigation. So instead of

```
<controller>foo</controller>
<action>bar</action>
<route>foobar</route>
<params>
    <bar>specialId</bar>
</params>
```

I used this instead

```
<controller>foo</controller>
<action>bar</action>
<route>foobar</route>
```

Simples.